# Is it possible to find an ellipse's axis lengths knowing the proportion and circumference?

Tags: geometry

If we have a symmetrical ellipse with, i.e. a circumference of 10 meters, and we know that the proportion between the axis a and b is of 5:3 (meaning a is 3x, and b is 5x), can we calculate the lengths?

I feel like this should be possible, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: what do you mean by "symmetrical ellipse"?

Comment: $a= 1.2, b = 2$ will give you circumference of $10.21$

Comment: My bad, with symmetrical ellipse I meant an ellipse. Not an oval, an ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

For an ellipse with semi-major axis $r_a$ and semi-minor axis $r_b$, the
circumference $L$ is given by the formula:

$$L = 4r_aE(e)$$
where $e = \sqrt{1 - \frac{r_b^2}{r_a^2}}$ is the eccentricity and
$$E(k) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta} d\theta$$
is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

For your case, you have $L = 10$ and $b > a$, so $b$ is the semi-major axis.
This means
$$b = \frac{L}{4E(e)} = \frac{10}{4E(\frac45)}$$

On [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), you can compute the value of $E(k)$ using the command `EllipticE[k^2]`. Throwing following command
`10/(4*EllipticE[(4/5)^2])` to WA, you will find
$$b\simeq 1.9587104722949813375395$$

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for!